# Is it safe to specialize in automatic weapons from the start?

Tags: atom-rpg

In Atom RPG, similarly to Fallout 1/2 you have to spend points to advance skills in specific types of weapons. It is not hard to guess, that akin to "energy weapons" (or "big guns") in Fallout, "automatic weapons" in Atom will be most powerful, but in "Fallout", those types of weapons weren't accessible until the mid-late part of the game. So is it safe to start spending points in this skill from the start and ignore all other weapon types?

I am currently barely few hours into the game (just "joined" the bandits in the abandoned factory) and the best weapon that I've found is rusty Nagant revolver for which I have barely 5 bullets. Which doesn't matter, because I couldn't hit the wide side of the barn from 2 meters, so instead I rely on good old kicks to the face that surprisingly have 99% chance to hit. How soon can I find even entry-level automatic weapon?

Comment: *In "Fallout", those types of weapons weren't accessible until the mid-late part of the game* - That's incorrect, and the one thing Atom has going for it. In F2, you run to NCR and steal a Bozar, then to SF to steal money and buy PA. Then it's game over. Atom doesn't have enough stuff in it to break the game. Fallout is *Skyrim w/ guns*. Atom is *Fallout w/o guns.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, specializing in only automatic weapons is perfectly reasonable.  You will be able to pick up a rusty AK-47 fairly early in the game as they're pretty commonly found on bandits.

> You can find a rusty AK fairly often in the smuggler's shop in the sewers of Krasnoznamenny, which requires a 1000 fee to enter (can be cheaper/free if you pass the skill checks), and a thief's pass to enter the smuggler's area, which you can get very early on.

*edit*
Previous trick is no longer doable.  Left in spoilers in case anyone's curious

> There used to be a way to beat the bandits in the beginning of the game to keep the ak-47 but that's no longer doable.

Answer (score 1):

I've only played it once because there's basically no endgame. You'll be done with the game before automatic weapons come into play. It has game mechanics and character creation similar to Fallout, but its world is lacking in locations and the random encounters are trite.

Equipment offerings are a little too sparse to put points into anything that doesn't help you cook, heal yourself, or wack people with shovels. All guns go to your companion who can actually hit with them.

Comment: That is... well quite untrue. I've bought my first automatic weapon at level 5, I am not investing in survival skills, because even with the "Glutton" characteristic I am never running out of food.

Comment: @Yasskier - Then the answer is level 5, but accessibility of a weapon includes ammo; *never* is how soon you can expect to find Fallout amounts of it, and imo never enough anyway to expend it at full auto. I either never learned how to farm, or that's not really a thing in this game. Baking a brick to sell for three ammo at a time doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: Uhh... I am not getting what you are trying to say... sorry. I was asking about how soon can I get any automatic weapon (which doesn't mean I'll be shooting in burst at rats), for which answer is indeed "around level 5". Ammo is a bit of a problem, but if you aren't silly and not shoot in burst to rats and wasps then you should be ok (carrying a spare gun with a different ammo type or a knife also helps).

Comment: @Yasskier - I've only played it once but *from start to finish* it is not "safe" to specialize in automatic weapons. iirc, I specialized in one of the types of guns and I had better stats in it then the companion, and they could hit and I couldn't. Maybe it was just my IRL perception, but I remember going *WTF, ok I guess I don't get the guns.*

Comment: Hmm, that is not my experience... But I was asking rather "would automatic weapons be available soon enough after start so I can specialiize in them from the beginning without spending points in another weapon types". The answer seems to be "yes"

Comment: @Yasskier where did you get it? I'm level 6, specialized in automatic weapons, but for me it's exactly like this answer says: let your sidekick do the fighting ...

Comment: @FelixDombek Uhh... it has been a while, but IIRC, I was fighting in melee and doing pretty well until I've found a first automatic weapon, which was I think before I've entered the major city. There is also apparently a trick that lets you save the weapon that you start with by killing the robbers, but it requires a specific build and dose of luck.